# ARQC/ ARPC Validation for CVN 14

Tags: java, hsm

We're trying to validate ARQC and generate ARPC for Mastercard using Thales PayShield-9000 HSM for CVN 14. We get response Code 01 (ARQC/TC/AAC/MPVV verification failure) and tried different combination for KW HSM command but still gets the same result. In KW Command host has to send Transaction Data and we doubt there has to be a issue in those data, also couldn't find any reference on how to send transaction data to the HSM. Below You can find some sample data that we already used on this and if you can point out any issue in those that would be a great help.

HSM Request[Hex]:>

```
0077303030324B573133554244344543303531313145443436443041463445314537343531353841463231303852619657502785013B009333340000000015000000000000000840000000000008402009280006C3D379580000930114250000044000DAC10000000000000000003B14DFD1F60DCFBC430000
```

HSM Response [Hex]:

```
0010303030324B58303156675727B234A31C
```

**Request breakdown**

```
007730303032    (header)
4B57 - KW    (hsm command)
31 - 1    (mode - Perform ARQC verification and EMV 4.x Method 1 ARPC generation )
33 - 3    (schema - EMV Option 'B' Card Key Derivation and EMV Common Session Key Derivation)
554244344543303531313145443436443041463445314537343531353841463231 - UBD4EC05111ED46D0AF4E1E745158AF21    (MDK)
3038 - 08    (pan+seq no length)
5261965750278501     (pan+seq no)
3B - ;     (delimiter)
0093     (ATC - 9F36)
3334 - 52     (txn data length)
0000000015000000000000000840000000000008402009280006C3D379580000930114250000044000DAC1000000000000000000     (txn data - refer breakdown below)
3B - ;     (delimiter)
14DFD1F60DCFBC43      (9F26 )
0000 - 00     (ARC)
```

**txn data breakdown**

```
000000001500 (9F02)
000000000000 (9F03)
0840 (9F1A)
0000000000 (95)
0840 (5F2A)
200928 (9A)
00 (9C)
06C3D379 (9F37)
5800 (82)
0093 (9F36)
0114250000044000DAC1000000000000000000 (9F10 with zero padding)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- CVN 14 (EMV CSK) is scheme ID '2', not '3' (this changes the way the session key is generated)
- Hard to say, but make sure that what you passed in PAN/PANseq is already preformatted  - I think you got that covered and PSN is 01 in your case, but you can double check

Answer (score 0):

You shoud add cryptogram information in your transaction data.